# Apache 2.4 Environment Variables

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

Apache 2.4.7 on Windows network.

When I look at phpinfo.php, in the Environment --> USERNAME section, it returns my windows username.

How can I access access that variable in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to access environment variables: `$_ENV['USERNAME']`.

For more information, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php